# Rotating a span in CSS within another element

Tags: css, rotation, transform

So I have an arrow that is rotated with a CSS transform when the element containing it is clicked. This works fine

```
<div><span class="arrow">&#x25BA;</span><h3>Some Text Goes Here</h3></div>
```

However, I need to place the arrow inside of the h3 element because the two need to stay inline and if the width of the parent element is too small the h3 element wraps down and ends up below the arrow instead of inline.

```
<div><h3><span class="arrow">&#x25BA;</span>Some Text Goes Here</h3></div>
```

When I do this the elements stay inline but the arrow no longer rotates.

Is there anyway to either:

1. Move the span back outside the elements but force the h3 to stay in the same line.
2. Get the span to rotate again within the h3 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the h3 stay in the same line:

```
h3 {
    display:inline;
}
```